# Connect/Authenticate Django Web App on SQL server using Key Vault, Azure AD or other (not using user-pass on my code)

Tags: sql-server, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have Django web app, with an SQL server db, deployed on my Azure subscription. I need to connect/authenticate my Web App to SQL server (still on my Azure subscription) but I can't using username-password on my code.
How can I do it? By key vault? By Azure AD?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that the best approach is to use the managed identities. My webapp can connect to the database using a AAD identity automatically provided by Azure. This is secure, without you needing to implement all kinds of difficult set-up.

Thank you again!